# Objects differ, but get trough .equals function and '==' operator

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, operator-keyword

I'm filling up a binary tree, and afterwards I try to get the parent of a certain leaf, trough a recursive method. Each node contains the String data; and let's say i'll only initialize the String data with "*" for each leaf.
In that method, i'm traversing trough the tree, until the given node(leaf) has been found, so I can return the parent.
After finding a leaf, I want to check if the node(leaf) is identical to the target I was searching for.
Sadly, this is not the case, and the method returns the parent first found leaf. 
I have used .equals() method and the "==" operator, but none of them work.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
    BinaryNode root = new BinaryNode("root",2);
    BinaryNode na = new BinaryNode("a",2);
    BinaryNode naLeaf1= new BinaryNode("*",0);
    BinaryNode naLeaf2 = new BinaryNode("*",0);
    na.addChild(naLeaf1);
    na.addChild(naLeaf2);
    BinaryNode nb = new BinaryNode("b",2);
    BinaryNode nbLeaf1= new BinaryNode("*",0);
    BinaryNode nbLeaf2 = new BinaryNode("*",0);
    nb.addChild(nbLeaf1);
    nb.addChild(nbLeaf2);
    root.addChild(na);
    root.addChild(nb);
```

This is the recursive method that traverses trough the binary tree.

```
public BinaryNode getParent(BinaryNode root, BinaryNode target) {

    if(root!=null) {
        for(BinaryNode ni: root.childeren) {
            if(!ni.data.equals("*")) {
                return  getParent(ni, target);
            }else  {
                if(ni.equals(target)) {
                    return  root;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

I have added an override for the .equals method, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object target) {
    if(target==null) return false;
    if(target==this) return true;
    if(!(target instanceof BinaryNode)) return false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you don't override equals, it behaves the same as ==.

Comment: Does BinaryNode override the default equals() implementation? If so, can you show it?

Comment: @DavidtenHove, I haven't implemented an override. I'll be doing that right away. Thanks !

Comment: @DavidtenHove, i have added the override, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Isn't there a way of checking the object's reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not the ´equals´ method, but the algorithm you use. First of all, doesn't the BinaryNode have the parent as a field? If not, then seriously consider adding that.

If you really do not want each node to know its parent, then you need to traverse the full tree, and not just one branch. Something like the following:

```
public BinaryNode getParentOf(BinaryNode target) {

    for(BinaryNode child: children) {
        if (child == target) {
            return this;
        }
        BinaryNode result = child.getParentOf(target);
        if (result != null ) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But seriously, make sure each node knows its parent.

Comment: You're right about the algorithm, and I took care of it. I also added the parent-property to the BinaryNode class. Thanks alot !

Answer (score 1):

In your .equals() override you'll need to do some calculation of what exactly separates two such objects. How about doing a check of the parameters you feed it, that way the objects are equal if their `root` and `target` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first `if` condition `!ni.data.equals("*")`. This evaluates to  `false`, right? Because you set data to '*' for all leafs. 
This `ni.equals(target)` evaluates to `false` as well, because there is nothing wrong with your `equals` method, and it works as expected.
This happenes for all children, you get out of the loop, and return `root`.

You need to rethink the logic of this function, it is just wrong. There is nothing wrong with the `equals` though (and you don't need to override it like this, could just use `==`).